# Entity Framework/Database First Build takes forever

Tags: c#, entity-framework, msbuild, edmx

i am using:
Visual Studio 2012
Entity Framework 5

I created my model from an Oracle Database with 1000 Tables. All of these are in one big edmx-file. (Not a good idea, i know, but at the moment no other way).

The problem is building the project. In VS the build takes 20 minutes (!). VS is unresponsive for that time. After that suddenly the report shows up in Output. Compiling the same project with MSBuild takes 4 seconds...

I could not find anything on the web on why this is happening. 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try watching this process in the Output window, don't just wait until it appears. There might be some useful information.

Comment: There is no entry or progress for the building time at all. Output is empty until after many minutes suddenly the success-message shows up. VS has a little animated item which also freezes during build time.

Comment: It seems the BuildAction "EntityDeploy" causes the major delay. I am searching what can be done here.